# Counting Possible combinations

Tags: statistics, combinations, dice

I do not now how to count the number of possibilities. Perhaps you can help.

I have 12 sided dice.
The sides are colored.
4 yellow
3 blue
2 green
1 red
1 black
1 white

If I roll 2 dice there are 16 possible combinations of two yellow sides showing out of a possible 144 combinations.

If I add dice, how do I count the number of possible yy combinations?

To complicate matters, the black dice are sometimes wild.
When they are, then I want to count the number of yellow and black.

If I have two dice, then I want to count the possible combinations of yy, yb, by, and bb. I can make a simple table and observe the number of instances. In this case, there are 25 possible combinations out of 144 possibilities.

When I have more than 2 dice how many yy combinations are possible given x dice?  And if I add the black dice how many yy, by, yb, bb combinations are possible given x dice?

Is there a formula that I can use to count the various combinations?  Tables become impractical when there are more than 2 dice.  I am unable to find formulas that help in counting the number of specific combinations our of the total number of combinations. In most examples, the identification of subset# out of total# seems to be done manually.

Comment: This site works best for single questions, perhaps the first part of a multi-part problem that give you trouble, perhaps the most puzzling part. But for optimal help here you need to show what you have tried and why you are having trouble finishing. That way we can try to give direct and helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the cases you've described, you just multiply the possibilities.  Just as you got $16=4\cdot4$ YY combinations, with $3$ dice you would have $64=4\cdot4\cdot4$ YYY combinations.  Similarly with four dice, there would be $4^4$ ways of getting all yellow.

For different colors of dice, you again multiply the possibilities.  For blue and yellow, three are $3\cdot4$ possibilities, and for yellow and blue there are $4\cdot3$ possibilities.  Usually, we would only do one multiplication and double the result.

When you have many dice, it would be very arduous to list all the possibilities.  There's a short cut using binomial coefficients, which I gather you are unfamiliar with.  There's a ton of stuff about it on the web.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the help.  I will research binomial coeffcients.

Answer (score 0):

This following is really a longish comment, not a solution, because it's not really feasible for large numbers of dice, but I think it's interesting to note that if we define
$$P=4 y + 3 b + 2 g + r + b + w$$
then if we expand $P^2$ we have counted all the possible outcomes of rolling two dice:
$$P^2 = 16 b^2+16 b g+8 b r+8 b w+32 b y+4 g^2+4 g r+4 g w+16 g y+r^2+2 r w+8 r y+w^2+8 w
   y+16 y^2$$
I.e. there are $16$ ways to roll blue-blue, $16$ ways to roll blue-green, $8$ ways to roll blue-red, etc.  And in general, expanding $P^n$ counts all the outcomes when rolling $n$ dice.  This process is only feasible for fairly small values of $n$, although it a computer algebra system can expand the range of application beyond the limits of pencil and paper computation.